# How do I insert multiple values into a postgres table at once?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, multiple-records

I have a table that I am trying to update multiple values at once.  Here is the table schema:

```
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers 
---------------+---------+-----------
 user_id       | integer | 
 subservice_id | integer |
```

I have the `user_id` and want to insert multiple `subservice_id`'s at once.  Is there a syntax in `Postgres` that will let me do something like this

```
insert into user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) values(1, [1, 2, 3]);
```

How would I do this?

Comment: If you want to insert them from a sequence, or using `generate_series` see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89544/16892

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) 
SELECT 1 id, x
FROM    unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22,33]) x
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9a006/1

Comment: I do not agree that using `unnest` should be the accepted answer, slick as it is. Default syntax is as mentioned by Scott. If you are on my team and use `unnest` I will ask you why and if you don't have a good answer, I will ask you to change it to the standard syntax

Answer (score 267):

Multi-value insert syntax is:

```
insert into table_name values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1);
```

When you need to specify columns:

```
insert into table_name (user_id, subservice_id) values
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (2, 1);
```

When you need to get the inserted `id` for example:

```
insert into table_name (user_id, subservice_id) values
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (2, 1)
returning id;
```

Comment: With either of these methods, is there a way to also return the `id`?

Comment: Yes, use returning. "insert into table (id, yada) values (1,2),(9,22) returning id;" etc

Comment: Also nowadays a CTE aka WITH statement often works well.

Comment: Integer values can able insert as like above. But while inserting text using above method its getting error like column does't exist. `insert into orders_cancel_reasons_infos values (1,1,"Changed my mind",1), (2,2,"Quality not satisfactory",1), (3,3,"Incompatible or not useful",1), (4,4,"Damaged product but shipping box is good",1), (5,5,"Items arrived too late",1), (6,6,"Missing part or accessories",1), (7,7,"Product and shipping box are damaged",1), (8,8,"Wrong item was sent",1), (9,9,"Defective item",1), (10,10,"Inaccurate description",1), (11,11,"Other",1);`

Comment: @sankarmuniyappa you'll have to use single quotes `' '` for the text that you're inserting.

so something like,

`insert into orders_cancel_reasons_infos values (1,1,'Changed my mind',1), (2,2,'Quality not satisfactory',1)` will work.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql) out for more on single and double-quotes.

Comment: This has the advantage of not being specific to Postgres too.

Comment: Not sure why krokodilko's answer is 'much slicker'... I think this should be the accepted answer as this is SQL standard syntax and also much easier to understand.

Answer (score 58):

A shorter version of krokodilko's answer:

```
insert into user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) 
values(1, unnest(array[1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: I think this is more expressive of intent than the accepted answer.  Is this standard SQL or PostgreSQL-specific?

Comment: Both answers are PostgreSQL-specific. The accepted answer is perhaps more easily translated to other databases, Oracle for example:

`insert into user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) 
select 1, column_value from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3))`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot more sense and is more readable than the accepted answer in my opinion.

Comment: A way to use this with information from another table:  `insert into user_subservices(user_id, subservice_id) 
values(1, unnest(ARRAY(select id from subservices where name like '%test%')));`

Comment: Why would you use non-standard syntax for something that is so widely implemented and has been in the SQL standard for decades? Use the syntax from [Scott Marlowe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20820950/286685) as it is standard and works on most DBs unchanged. And is understood by any dev that knows standard SQL.

Answer (score 21):

A slightly related answer because I keep finding this question every time I try to remember this solution. **Insert multiple rows with multiple columns**:

```
insert into user_subservices (user_id, subservice_id)
select *
from unnest(array[1, 2], array[3, 4]);
```

Comment: Or you can insert an array of integers into one column.

Answer (score 4):

More robust example, for when you need to insert multiple rows into some table for every row in another table:

```
INSERT INTO user_subservices (user_id, subservice_id)
SELECT users.id AS user_id, subservice_id
FROM users
CROSS JOIN unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3]) subservice_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

A good way to import values once but avoid duplicates is as follows:

```
insert into schema.mytable (col1,col2) 
select col1, col2 from schema.mytable 
UNION
values 
('row1-col1','row1-col2'),
('row2-col1','row2-col2'),
('row3-col1','row3-col2')
except
select col1, col2 from schema.mytable;
```

Answer (score -2):

For multiple values, this function might be helpful.

> This function generates multiple values

```js
const _multiInsert = arrOfValues => {
    // removes lastCharacter
    const _remLastChar = str => str.slice(0, str.length - 1);

      let foramttedQuery = '';

      arrOfValues.forEach(row => {
        let newRow = '';
        for (const val of Object.values(row)) {
          let newValue = '';
          if (typeof val === 'string') newValue = `'${val}',`;
          else newValue = `${val},`;
          newRow = newRow.concat(newValue);
        }

        foramttedQuery = foramttedQuery.concat(`(${_remLastChar(newRow)}),`);
      });

      return _remLastChar(foramttedQuery);
    };

    const arr_Of_Values = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "SAMPLE_NAME_1",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "SAMPLE_NAME2",
        }
    ]

    const query_template = `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES ${_multiInsert(arr_Of_Values)}`
    
 console.log(query_template)
```

Comment: WARNING: This example uses non-parametrized queries and it's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide an example with parametrize query