# What is the difference between single quotes and double quotes in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to PostgresSQL.I tried

```
select * from employee where employee_name="elina";
```

But that results error as follows:

```
ERROR: column "elina" does not exist.
```

Then I tried by replacing double quotes with single quotes as follows:

```
select * from employee where employee_name='elina';
```

It result fine..So what is the difference between single quotes and double quotes in postgresql.If we can't use double quotes in postgres query,then if any other use for this double quotes in postgreSQL?

Comment: Single quotes are the proper delimited for a string constant.  Period.

Comment: If in doubt, read the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Double quotes are for names of tables or fields. Sometimes You can omit them. The single quotes are for string constants. This is the SQL standard. In the verbose form, your query looks like this:

```
select * from "employee" where "employee_name"='elina';
```

Comment: I wonder what value SQL actually compares to when you indicate `"elina"`. Also wonder why this isn't considered a syntax error. It must impact every SQL user on earth at least once.

Comment: @jarmod In the SQL standard, "elina" would be a value from a column of that name.

Answer (score 51):

As explained in [the PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS):

> A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters bounded by single quotes (`'`), for example `'This is a string'`. To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes, e.g., `'Dianne''s horse'`. Note that this is not the same as a double-quote character (`"`).

Elsewhere [on the same page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> There is a second kind of identifier: the *delimited identifier* or *quoted identifier*. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes (`"`). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word. So `"select"` could be used to refer to a column or table named "select", whereas an unquoted `select` would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when used where a table or column name is expected.

TL;DR: Single quotes for string constants, double quotes for table/column names.

Comment: Another usage of the quoted identifier is for role names: if you want a user to have a `.` in the username, double-quotes is what makes it legal syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Well single quotes are used for string literals and double quotes are used for escaping DB objects like table name / column name etc.

Specifically, double quotes are used for escaping a column/table name if it's resemble to any reserve/key word. Though every RDBMS have their own way of escaping the same (like backtique in `MySQL` or square bracket in `SQL Server`) but using double quotes is ANSI standard.