# sequelize postgresql update migration

Tags: postgresql, migration, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize and PostgreSQL and trying to do a simple update via migrations that finds a specific value and udpates it. I have achieved alter table migrations without problem, I must be missing something simple, I can confirm I have a myTable and there is a field named "name" and an entry has a value of "bob".

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE 'myTable' SET name = 'bob' WHERE name = 'fred'`)
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "'myTable'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it not be

```
queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE myTable SET name = 'bob' WHERE name = 'fred'`)
```

Single quotes are for proper strings, you could double quotes though.
This answer has more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql)

Comment: Yeah double quotes, strange I thought I had tried that, any all working, thanks.