# Why I am not able to refer to my sequence with double quotes in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

I have created sequence in postgres.

```
postgres=# create sequence my_sequence start 5 minvalue 3 increment 1 cycle;
CREATE SEQUENCE
```

Now I am trying to query the next value from the sequence.

```
postgres=# select nextval("my_sequence");
ERROR:  column "my_sequence" does not exist
LINE 1: select nextval("my_sequence");
```

But it's giving me error, that sequence doesn't exists. But, when I use single quote with the sequence_name, then it works fine :-

```
postgres=# select nextval('my_sequence');
 nextval
---------
       5
(1 row)
```

But as per [difference between single quote and double quote in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql), double quotes can be used with any user defined sql object. so, accordingly my_sequence is also user-defined object. So, why I am not able to access it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Use single quotes, like in

```
SELECT nextval('my_sequence');
```

The argument to `nextval` is not an identifier, but has type `regclass`:

```
\df nextval
                       List of functions
   Schema   |  Name   | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | nextval | bigint           | regclass            | normal
(1 row)
```

`regclass` is a convenience type that internally is identical to the unsigned 4-byte object identifier type `oid`, but has a [type input function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xtypes.html) that accepts a table, index or sequence name as input.

So you can call `nextval` with the *name* of the table as parameter, and a string is surrounded by single, not double quotes.