# LEFT JOIN in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, left-join

Ok what's wrong with this SQL query:

```
select j.* from judge as j 
left join user as u on j.user_id = u.id 
where u.email="john@example.com";
ERROR:  column "john@example.com" does not exist
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using double quotes where you should actually be using single quotes. 
Single quotes denote values, while double quotes represent columns and tables, etc.
[You can find out more about the difference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql)