# ERROR: column "***" does not exist in dense rank function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-literals

I would like to add columns by following window function.

```
select goods_code,event_code ,DENSE_RANK() Over (
Order By case when goods_code = "aaaa" then 1 end,
         case when event_code = "a" then 1 end)
from atai.pricing_pattern
```

but it returned following error.

```
ERROR:  column "aaaa" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ENSE_RANK() Over (Order By case when goods_code = "aaaa" the...
                                                             ^
```

What is the root cause of this? if someone has opinion,will you please let me know
Thanks

Comment: Use single quotes here. See this question for an explanation about single vs double quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS   4.1.1. Identifiers and Key Words

Comment: See [String constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) in the Postgres manual