# Extract existing mentions from bio in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a profile table with name, bio and other fields (mentions is not one of them).
How can I write a query in PostgreSQL that select all the rows based on certain condition (say name="John Doe" in this case) and get all the mentions that is the exists in profile table.

FYI people can put anything after '@' it may or may not exists in the profile table. (I need to check if extracted mentions exists in db or not, if exists only then make them a part of `mentions`)

**Query Result Should Be**

| name | bio | mentions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | Ex - @meta | @tesla | @abc | ["meta", "tesla"] |

**Profile Table**

| name | bio |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | Ex - @meta, @tesla, @abc |
| meta | We do social media |
| tesla | We make cool stuff |

I tried following query

```
SELECT *, ARRAY( 
    SELECT
      DISTINCT unnest(regexp_matches(p.bio, '@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', 'g'))
    FROM
      profile pwg
    WHERE
    pwg.id = p.id
  ) AS mentions 
  FROM profile p where name = "John Doe"
```

But this simply extracts all the mentions i.e ["meta", "tesla", "abc"].

How can I write a query that can extract only those mentions that exists in profile table ie ["meta", "tesla"]

Comment: Try this
`SELECT
    p1.name,
    p1.bio,
    JSON_ARRAY(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p1.bio, ' - ', -1), ', ', 1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p1.bio, ' - ', -1), ', ', -1)
    ) AS mentions
FROM Profile AS p1
WHERE p1.name = 'John Doe';`

Comment: Don't spam-tag unrelated dbms's. Your question will only get less attention.

Comment: And don't store data as comma separated items, it will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: And tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: Is this a MySQL problem or a PostgreSQL problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase its in Postgres, I've edited the question

Comment: @SenthilPNathan Thanks for suggestions but I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: SenthiPNathan's suggestion was for MySQL, because you had mistakenly tagged the question [tag:mysql]. MySQL has a SUBSTRING_INDEX() function, but PostgreSQL doesn't. This is why you should tag your questions accurately, because you may get suggestions that don't work in the software you are really using. By doing that, you waste your time and the time of other people who try to make suggestions.

Comment: @BillKarwin Sorry. I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: @ShreyasChorge, how about this?
`SELECT
    name,
    REPLACE(bio, ',', ' |') AS bio,
    CASE
        WHEN bio LIKE '%tesla%' AND bio LIKE '%meta%' THEN json_build_array('meta', 'tesla') 
        WHEN bio LIKE '%meta%' THEN json_build_array('meta')
        WHEN bio LIKE '%tesla%' THEN json_build_array('tesla')
    END AS mentions
FROM Profile
WHERE name = 'John Doe';`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan Thanks for suggestion but I don't jst want to extract mentions from the bio, but also check if the extracted bio exists in profile table

Comment: @SenthilPNathan I have updated the question for better understanding

Comment: Please read: [What is the difference between single quotes and double quotes in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396195/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-postgresql)

Comment: @ShreyasChorge, its bit clumsy but check it.
`WITH ExtractedMentions AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        p1.name,
        UNNEST(regexp_matches(p1.bio, '@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', 'g')) AS mention
    FROM Profile AS p1
    WHERE p1.name = 'John Doe'
)
SELECT
    E.name AS name,
    p1.bio AS bio,
    JSON_AGG(p.name) AS mentions
FROM ExtractedMentions E
JOIN Profile p ON p.name = E.mention
JOIN Profile p1 ON p1.name = 'John Doe'
GROUP BY E.name, p1.bio;`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan Thanks for the suggestion but this query will mixup bios and names. The accepted answer is the solution that solves this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   p.name,
   ARRAY_AGG(m.m[1]) as mentions
FROM profile p
CROSS JOIN regexp_matches(p.bio, '@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', 'g') m
INNER JOIN profile p2 ON p2.name = m.m[1]
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

output:

| id | name | mentions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | {meta,tesla} |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/s2AljKxG)

First get the `mentions`

```
SELECT
   p.id,
   p.name,
   m.m[1]
FROM profile p
CROSS JOIN regexp_matches(p.bio, '@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', 'g') m
INNER JOIN profile p2 ON p2.name = m.m[1]
```

then group them.

Comment: Thanks this works...!! 
Just a correction instead of `ARRAY_AGG(m.m[1]) as mentions`
we need to do `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT m.m[1]) as mentions` or else mentions will have duplicate values

Comment: @ShreyasChorge: You should have provided data with duplicates, then I would have added the `DISTINCT` 