# postgresql time series single time stamp with array inferred time

Tags: arrays, postgresql, time-series

I have a table which looks like this:-

```
CREATE TABLE packet_test_short_array
(
  packet_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  frame_count integer,
  packet_data int2[200],
  CONSTRAINT packet_test_short_array_pk PRIMARY KEY (packet_date)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE);
```

There is a single timestamp and an array of measurements which themselves are offset from the main timestamp by say 1 second * their array position.

i.e., the last measurement in the array at pos 199 is 199 seconds after the main timestamp.

I want to unnest the array and give each member an incrementing timestamp of (as above) 1 second.

[The rather nifty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815028/how-do-i-insert-multiple-values-into-a-postgres-table-at-once) reply by krokodilco is almost what I want...

```
SELECT 1 id, x
FROM    unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22,33]) x
```

except the '1' isn't incrementing.

I am hoping this is an easy one but I can't spot it.

I'd be very grateful for your help & insight please.

EDIT: Example...

So say I have one timestamp with an array containing 10 values, like this:-

```sql
'2016-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp AS packet_date, ARRAY[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] AS packet_data
```

I want to extrapolate the one timestamp into an ascending time series with an interval of say 1 minute; i.e. unnest the single timestamp  into 10 rows each with it's own distinct timstamp for each corresponding value 1 minute apart. A bit like this...
`packet_date, packet_value` (unnested from `packet_data`)

```sql
"2016-06-01 00:00:00", 0  
"2016-06-01 00:01:00", 1  
"2016-06-01 00:02:00", 2  
"2016-06-01 00:03:00", 3  
"2016-06-01 00:04:00", 4  
"2016-06-01 00:05:00", 5  
"2016-06-01 00:06:00", 6  
"2016-06-01 00:07:00", 7  
"2016-06-01 00:08:00", 8  
"2016-06-01 00:09:00", 9
```

I know how I can generate the time series...

```sql
select generate_series(min('2016-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp), max('2016-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp+INTERVAL '10 minutes'), interval '1 minute')
```

but can't see how to match it with its corresponding array member/value which can be simulated like this...

```sql
select unnest(ARRAY[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply a time interval (in this case one minute) by an integer (the ordinality of unnested array) e.g.:

```
with my_table(packet_date, packet_data) as (
values 
    ('2016-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, ARRAY[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
)
select 
    packet_date + '1m'::interval* (ordinality - 1) as packet_date, 
    unnest as packet_data
from my_table,
lateral unnest(packet_data) with ordinality;

     packet_date     | packet_data 
---------------------+-------------
 2016-06-01 00:00:00 |           0
 2016-06-01 00:01:00 |           1
 2016-06-01 00:02:00 |           2
 2016-06-01 00:03:00 |           3
 2016-06-01 00:04:00 |           4
 2016-06-01 00:05:00 |           5
 2016-06-01 00:06:00 |           6
 2016-06-01 00:07:00 |           7
 2016-06-01 00:08:00 |           8
 2016-06-01 00:09:00 |           9
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I am looking for - I didn't want to store the data as discrete values with duplicated meta data and I didn't want to normalise the table into two tables. Meta data with the data in an array 'does it for me'.

So thank you very much @klin, I now have a proof of concept.

Comment: One further point, it is really important that the data comes out in order of it's position in the array. In this example, the data at position 0 in the array is for the exact time specified in the original timestamp; The data in position 99 is the data for 99 minutes after the original timestamp.

i.e., the timstamp of the data is implicit from it's position in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `with ordinality`:

```
SELECT x.id, x.x
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22,33]) with ordinality x(x, id);
```

In your case, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as id, x.x
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,22,33]) x(x);
```

Comment: thanks for this, I am struggling. I have added an example at the end of my post...