# How do I insert multiple rows at once which contains two foreign keys from two different tables in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS site_shipping_method_configuration (        
              id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
              shipping_method_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
              custom_id VARCHAR(255),
              PRIMARY KEY(shipping_method_id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.channel (
              channel_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
              channel_name VARCHAR(50),
              PRIMARY KEY(channel_id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.shipping_method_channel_mapping (
              id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
              channel_id integer NOT NULL,
              shipping_method_id integer NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY(id),
              FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES channel (channel_id),
              FOREIGN KEY (shipping_method_id) REFERENCES site_shipping_method_configuration (id));
```

I have to insert multiple values at once in 3rd table which contains two foreign keys from two tables (1st and 2nd). I already have values in first two tables.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: how do i insert multiple values in 3rd table at once? Any optimized query is there!

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815028/how-do-i-insert-multiple-values-into-a-postgres-table-at-once

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the column site_shipping_method_configuration.id, which is referenced by a foreign key in, is not unique.
We solve this by adding  `UNIQUE` in the table definition.

Everything now works correctly.

> ```
> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
> /* added to avoid function not found error  */
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS site_shipping_method_configuration (
> id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY UNIQUE, /* ==========   UNIQUE CONSTRAINT ADDED  ======   */
> shipping_method_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() , 
> custom_id VARCHAR(255), 
> PRIMARY KEY(shipping_method_id));
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.channel ( 
> channel_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
> channel_name VARCHAR(50), 
> PRIMARY KEY(channel_id));
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.shipping_method_channel_mapping ( 
> id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
> channel_id integer NOT NULL, 
> shipping_method_id integer NOT NULL, 
> PRIMARY KEY(id), 
> FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES channel (channel_id), 
> FOREIGN KEY (shipping_method_id) REFERENCES site_shipping_method_configuration (id));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO site_shipping_method_configuration (custom_id) VALUES (1);
> INSERT INTO public.channel (channel_name) VALUES ('test channel');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO public.shipping_method_channel_mapping 
> (channel_id, shipping_method_id ) VALUES
> (1,1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM site_shipping_method_configuration;
> SELECT * FROM public.channel;
> SELECT * FROM public.shipping_method_channel_mapping ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | shipping_method_id                   | custom_id
> -: | :----------------------------------- | :--------
>  1 | 2a1ac9aa-3b96-4e43-968a-06a2e18d2be1 | 1        
>
> channel_id | channel_name
> ---------: | :-----------
>          1 | test channel
>
> id | channel_id | shipping_method_id
> -: | ---------: | -----------------:
>  1 |          1 |                  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4b3fc8f2b91b1624646de96b4bb2d8b2)*